# GPT doesn't read JSON files well

Tags: python, chatgpt-api

I am converting the statistical analysis excel file to JSON format with Python and then reading it to GPT to create a report automatically.

The report is generated, but it doesn't show the exact numbers of the excel source data.

I'm not sure if it's the original data or the conversion to JSON that's the problem

Which part could be the problem?

```py
# Function to automatically detect the encoding of a JSON file

def detect_encoding(file_path):
    # Open the file. 
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        raw_data = file.read()
    result = chardet.detect(raw_data)
    encoding = result\["encoding"\]
    return encoding

# Function to convert a JSON file to a string

def read_json_file(file_path, encoding):
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding=encoding) as file:
        json_data = json.load(file)
    json_string = json.dumps(json_data, ensure_ascii=False)
    return json_string

# a function to process the question and answer

def process_question(json_file_path):

    instructions = ("Please take the data in the given json file and create a report in the format of the examples below.  Please select the minimum value for the maximum value and the average for the minimum value."
                    "Example 1: 'Out of 318 companies responding to the survey, 75.0% are currently in crisis compared to the previous quarter, with an average of 2.23 points, indicating a somewhat crisis situation compared to the previous quarter.' "
                    "Example 2: 'The proportion of companies that are currently in crisis compared to the previous quarter (by year of establishment) is highest in companies with 15 to 20 years of business history at 82.4%, and the average is 2.49 for companies with 4 to 7 years of business history, indicating a somewhat worse situation compared to the previous quarter. "
                    "Example 3: 'The proportion of companies that are currently in crisis compared to the previous quarter (by main product) is highest among companies that mainly provide knowledge services at 84.2%, and the average is 2.59 for companies that provide knowledge services, indicating that they are somewhat in crisis compared to the previous quarter."
                    "Example 4: 'By industry, the proportion of companies in crisis compared to the previous quarter was highest in the textile and apparel industry with 76.5%, and the average was 2.11 in the textile and apparel industry, indicating a somewhat severe crisis compared to the previous quarter. "
                    "Example 5: 'Please create a report in the same format as each example, and use the values in the JSON file."
                    )
    
    messages = [
        { "role": "assistant", "content" : instructions}
    ]
    
    # detect the encoding of the JSON file and pass it to the assistant
    file_encoding = detect_encoding(json_file_path)
    json_string = read_json_file(json_file_path, file_encoding)
    messages.append({"role": "user", "content": json_string})
    
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
        messages=messages,
        max_tokens=2000 
    )
    
    assistant_content = completion.choices[0].message["content"].strip()
    
    return assistant_content
```

Comment: Provide instructions as `system`, not `assistant`. You could also play with the `temperature` variable.

Comment: Also, take a look at [Guidance](https://github.com/microsoft/guidance).